# Blank screen on first Ubuntu boot

Tags: boot

After a number of failed attempts, I thought I had successfully installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0, but I'm not quite there yet.

After asking for the crypt password, the system goes into disk checking and then the screen turns black. And then nothing.

Does anyone have any suggestion how I would go about trouble shooting this issue?

Comment: Can you go to tty? Using ctrl + alt + F1-12(any of this till you see some login screen)

Comment: Ok, that did something, it gives me the following message: [drm:si_dp_power_state [radeon]] *ERROR* si-restrict_performance_levels-before_switch failed

Comment: is there a login screen if you try `ctrl + alt +F1` `ctrl + alt + F2` etc.?

Comment: I rebooted, then tried CTL-ALT-Fx again, and now instead of that error I got a log-in prompt. I'm now logged in. I'm guessing this is a display driver issue..?

Comment: may, can post the output of `sudo systemctl status gdm3`?

Comment: That gives a bunch of output, with Started Gnome Display Manager at the bottom. Does that help?

Comment: is there an error? or fail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123317/discussion-between-lucki1000-and-ruben).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's now using lightdm instead of gdm3 and since then everything is fine, the cause of this gdm3 problem is unsolved. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123317/discussion-between-lucki1000-and-ruben

Comment: Thank you, lucki1000, for providing excellent assistence. So happy I can log on now!

Answer (score 0):

can you reinstall ubuntu ?
i am assuming that you are on UEFI

just go for BIOS(legacy) install , and you will have the smoothest install ever

just set boot mode to bios only(non uefi) from your pc bios then boot into the usb , and you shall be good to go

Comment: Why he should use Bios? There is no technical reason why he can't use uefi or?

Comment: i am telling this from my past experience , i was installing ubuntu 20.10 (erase disk) on my laptop using UEFI , i still dont know was the reason it only gave me single error "fatal error installing grub cant proceed" , ,https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI states you need boot repair tool on some systems to make uefi install work ,,,it fixed succecfuly but then i experienced a buggy install , with a non responding mouse and touchpad , and graphic crashes

,,, after that i retried installing on BIOS and everything worked like voila,,

Comment: ,, this seems to happen when single-booting, ,, previosly i installed it with dual boot with windows(uefi) and ubuntu(uefi) and that went smoothly

Comment: This is my 4th reinstall acutally. The first two times the issue seems to be with the installation medium, so I changed to a larger pendrive. The third time, I suppose it was the same issue I am facing now, but it was without disk encryptio, so it skipped the crypt password part and went blank straight away. Edit: see my comment about the newly found error message on the main post.